# UIWebView/WKWebView and youtube streaming videos

Tags: swift, uiwebview, youtube-api, wkwebview, swift4

I'm trying to play streaming videos in my app but it's not working in WKWebView/UIWebView.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/PP2G3dm_fsc")
let webView = WKWebView()
webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: webViewHeight)
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.addSubview(webView)
```

This video (PP2G3dm_fsc) is restricted, but I've got the same error message with any video (even with my own). At the same time this url works in my browser like a charm.

[image]

Do I have to use YTPlayerView to make it work?

**update:** I have the same results with YTPlayerView

Answer (score 0):

You can use [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

> It is an open source library that helps you embed a YouTube iframe player into an iOS application. The library creates a [**`UIWebView`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and a bridge between your application’s Objective-C code and the YouTube player’s JavaScript code, thereby allowing the iOS application to control the YouTube player.

This will make your implementation easier with the use of the library. You can also check their [GitHub page](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/tree/master/Project/youtube-player-ios-example) for sample implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I've tried that, and youtube-ios-player-helper doesn't work as well. I'll try their sample project, thanks.